# Name 'cost' not defined error line player.reduce_mp(cost)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Getting a `NameError: name 'cost' is not defined at player.reduce_mp(cost)`

```
elif index == 1:
    player.choose_magic()
    magic_choice = int(input('Choose magic'))-1
    magic_dmg = player.generate_spell_damage()
    spell = player.get_spell_name(magic_choice)
    cost = player.get_spell_mp_cost(magic_choice)
    current_mp = player.get_mp()

    if cost > current_mp:
        print(bcolors.FAIL + '\nNot enough MP\n' + bcolors.ENDC)
        continue

player.reduce_mp(cost)
enemy.take_damage(magic_dmg)
print(bcolors.OKBLUE + '\n' + spell + 'deals', str(magic_dmg), 'points of damage' + bcolors.ENDC)
```

Comment: Without seeing the code around that area, it's difficult to say, but as `cost` is only shown within the `elif` part, it looks like it's out of scope when you come to use it within `player.reduce_mp(cost)`

Comment: Show where you think cost is defined.

Answer (score 0):

How about now:

```
elif index==1:
    player.choose_magic()
    magic_choice=int(input('Choose magic'))-1
    magic_dmg=player.generate_spell_damage()
    spell=player.get_spell_name(magic_choice)
    cost=player.get_spell_mp_cost(magic_choice)

    current_mp=player.get_mp()

    if cost>current_mp:
        print(bcolors.FAIL+ '\nNot enough MP\n'+bcolors.ENDC)
        continue

    player.reduce_mp(cost)
    enemy.take_damage(magic_dmg)
    print(bcolors.OKBLUE+'\n'+spell+'deals',str(magic_dmg),'points of damage'+bcolors.ENDC)
```

Answer (score -1):

The thing is that you're using the 'cost' value outside the scope of its declaration.
If your final if statement is well indented, then add

```
int cost
```

In the printing scope, before its assignment (before the elif, without indentation). This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules) will explain you further this concept.

Comment: ``int cost`` is not valid python. Also, no scopes are involved here: if statements (and else/elif) do not open any scopes in python.